# rc.subr can't access file?

Tags: permissions, freebsd, rc

On FreeBSD 8.3 I'm running script (as root):

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo/foo.sh start
```

content is typical:

```
. /etc/rc.subr
name="foo"
rcvar=${name}_enable
load_rc_config ${name}
required_files=${foo_conf}
```

in `/etc/rc.d.local` I have:

```
foo_conf=/cf/foo/config/foorc
```

And when I start it I get:

```
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo.sh: WARNING: /cf/foo/config/foorc is not readable.
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/foo.sh: WARNING: failed precmd routine for foo
```

But when I run application (`/usr/local/bin/foo`) directly with `-f` parameter as `/cf/foo/config/foorc` application starts normal.

Permission for `foorc` file: `-rwxr-xr-x` and for directory: `drwxr-xr-x`.

Fragment in rc.subr looks like:

```
check_required_before()
{
    for _f in $required_files; do
    if [! -r "${_f}" ]; then
    warn "${_f} is not readable"
    fi
    done
}
```

It is permission problem or what?

Answer (score 0):

Something could be wrong with the rest of your path. As a proof of concept:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /tmp/a/b/c
$ date | sudo cat > /tmp/a/b/c/hello
$ stat -x /tmp/a/b/c/hello
...
Mode: (0644/-rw-r--r--)
...
$ stat -x /tmp/a/b/c/
...
Mode: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)
...
$ sudo chmod 700 /tmp/a/b/
$ cat /tmp/a/b/c/hello    
cat: /tmp/a/b/c/hello: Permission denied
```

I would suggest checking that both /cf and /cf/foo have read and execute permissions for the user that will be running the command.

I am guessing that you are running

```
/usr/local/bin/foo -f /cf/foo/config/foorc
```

as root, and that's why there is no issue with the permissions.